# gcloud cbt createtable command fails with rpc error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-bigtable

Getting an RPC error while trying create a bigtable in Gcloud.

```
~/ > cbt createtable my-table

2018/04/24 13:45:03 -creds flag unset, will use gcloud credential

2018/04/24 13:45:14 Creating table: rpc error: code = NotFound desc = Failed to read: projects/{project-id}/instances/bigtabledev
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Found the answer. It was happening because .cbtrc file requires instance ID associated to variable instance. Instead of Instance ID, I had instance name configurred in .cbtrc

Comment: Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please move your solution into an answer and [accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @ForeverLearner for providing the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50007968/gcloud-cbt-createtable-command-fails-with-rpc-error#comments-50007968) in this comment.

Comment: @Misha added it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bottleneck was that .cbtrc file requires instance ID associated to variable instance. Instead of Instance ID, I had instance name configured in .cbtrc

Comment: Thanks for moving your comment into an answer! Can you please [accept it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks.